# Time complexity and type of sorting algorithm for this code

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Can someone tell me what type of sorting is this? Is this still O(n) even after adding the filter?

```
const sortMe = arr => {

    let sorted = new Array(arr.length).fill(0);

    for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
        if(sorted.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1) 
            sorted[arr[i] - 1] = arr[i];
        else sorted.splice(sorted.indexOf(arr[i]), 0, arr[i]);
    }

    return sorted.filter(x => x !== 0);
}

console.log(sortMe([3,15,2,1,18,2,5,6,7,12,3,1,2,3]))
```

Sorry for asking this, I'm not a computer science graduate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's O(n)^2.

First, you are going through the loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++){
```

That makes it O(n) automatically without adding any processing. Then, in addition to that, you're also using `indexOf` (in both branches).

```
 sorted.splice(sorted.indexOf(arr[i]), 0, arr[i]);
```

`indexOf` starts with the first element and then moves to each element stepwise until it reaches the sought element. So, for each step in O(n), you are calling a function which iterates over the entire list, this means you are calling O(n), n times, making it O(n*n), or O(n^2).

---

Note: you might not think it is O(n^2) because you are processing a subset of the list for `indexOf`. However, the average case is still looking at a list of length n/2.

You also asked about adding a filter function. This might make it seem like it should be O(n^2 + n).

For big-O notation, you remove all constants: O-notation is about complexity and growth of equations with larger inputs. Therefore it's either "constant, logarithmic, linear, exponential, factorial, etc", not "Factorial + logarithmic."